# How do I create a loop to delete all rows after 450?

Tags: for-loop, google-apps-script, google-sheets-api, delete-row

I am working on a spreadsheet that populates from a google form. I figured out how to delete all the data after each week to reset the form and spreadsheet. The problem I am facing is that the form adds new rows with each entry. Eventually the spreadsheet will reach the row limit but I need the form to continue for several years. The code I have thus far is:

```
herefunction clearRange() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');
  sheet.getRange('A8:V100').clearContent();

  for (row>=451; row<1000; row++) {
  sheet.deleteRow(451)
}
}
```

As it resolves it gives me an error saying: ReferenceError: "row" is not defined. I am new to the programing world and would appreciate any assistance.

Comment: I think `row>=451` (in the loop initialise) should be `var row=451`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
function clearRange() {

        var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Form Responses 1');
        var rows = sheet.getDataRange();
        var numRows = rows.getNumRows();
        sheet.getRange('A8:V100').clearContent();

        for (var row=451; row <= numRows; row++) {
            sheet.deleteRow(row);
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. It deleted about 100 rows and then gave the error: Those rows are out of bounds. It gets me closer to a solution for which i am grateful. by running it multiple times it will delete about another 100. Not sure why it is giving the error.

Comment: I edited my answer, this should be more appropriate.

Comment: Thank you for your help. It does exactly what I needed it to.

Comment: You should delete them backwards from last to first to improve performance. Also as it is could go out of bounds.

Comment: Several hundred calls to the API is never a good idea. Refer to @ZigMandel's answer... it is much more appropriate.

Answer (score 2):

While the other answer works its slow and will break when there are many rows.
Use deleteRows instead to delete them all with a single call.
https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#deleteRows(Integer,Integer)